# UDF to make a kind of Substitute Array-Function

Tags: excel, vba, function, substitution, udf

I'm trying to make a function that not only substitute one text with another,
but substitute a set of values from a range with another lateral set of values.

I have this:

```
Public Function SubstituteRange(RangeWithText As Range, TwoColumnMatrix As Range) As String
Dim Text As String
Text = "/" & RangeWithText.Value & "/"
'as example st like this: "/" & "1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8" & "/" = "/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/"
Dim SearchForRange As Range
Set SearchForRange = TwoColumnMatrix.Columns(1)
'let us say "A1:A4" with /2/ /3/ /4/ /5/ in each cell    
Dim ReplaceWithRange As Range
Set ReplaceWithRange = TwoColumnMatrix.Columns(2)
'let us say "B1:B4" with /9/ /10/ /11/ /12/ in each cell
Dim i As Integer
SubstituteRange = Text
For i = 1 To SearchForRange.Rows.Count '4 rows
SubstituteRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(SubstituteRange, _
SearchForRange.Item(i), ReplaceWithRange.Item(i))
Next i
End Function
```

but this return an "#Value!" error,
can somebody help me with this ?
I expected to get from this example something like "/1/9/10/11/12/6/7/8/" but I didn't get it.
thank you in advance.

Comment: VBA has `Replace()`, which will do the work of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute()`

Comment: just as question,. which of both uses less resources?

Comment: `Replace()` is about 6-7 times faster in the quick test I just ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function MultiReplace(v, rng)
    Dim rw As Range, rv
    rv = "/" & v & "/"
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        rv = Replace(rv, rw.Cells(1).Value, rw.Cells(2).Value)
    Next rw
    MultiReplace = rv
End Function
```

Comment: thank you Tim, this surpasses what I did,. you combine speed and easiness-to-read. I will change my code for this one

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the substitute statement into this (tested):

```
SubstituteRange = Application.Substitute(SubstituteRange, _
SearchForRange.cells(i).Text, ReplaceWithRange.Cells(i).Text)
```

Comment: you're right!! thank you very much, I did these changes and it works perfectly, but why works with cells(I) and not with item(I) ??
and another one, why works with application.substitute and not with application.worksheetfunction.substitute ??

Comment: for the second question, it is simply shorter, both work. For the first question, both should work, but I and most developers are used to use cells.

Comment: I'm thinking that my code didn't work because I use item(I) and it's used more in the environment of OOP, may because it hasn't only one value (as does the default value of Cell, that is Value)